# Motherboard power-up issue

Tags: power, repair, motherboard

I am not entirely sure this is the place for my question but it is the closes i found.
I am not an electrical/electronics engineer and this is my first attempt to what i am trying to do so please be patient and polite if my question is non-technical/specific or too broad.

I am trying to diagnose a motherboard which does not power up. No fans spinning, no PSU mains.
It an old one (ASUS p5k) with the P35 - ICH9 intel chipsets.

Trying to diagnose the issue i found out about the power-up sequence.
To my understanding the power-on pins on the board are high and when button is pressed they get low.
This signal (psin) goes to the SuperIO chip (winbond W83627DHG).
This chip sets low another output (psout) which goes to the southbridge.
It also sets the RSMRST signal to high (also going to the south bridge).
Then it receives the susb# signal from southbridge in order to set the PSON low and start the PSU main.

5/3.3 V standby is ok. PSU starts with ok voltages when manually triggered (PS-ON - ground connection).
Everything in the sequence seems to be ok to the point where i am supposed to receive the susb signal from the southbridge. No such signal is present.

I suspect a problem with the southbridge.
I have checked IDE,USB,SATA and pCI slots for shortings and they all seems to be ok.
What is the next step? in way that if someone who has more experice from me on repairs what would he suggest?

Thanks again.

Comment: This really is off topic here.   I suggest something like Toms hardware forum.

Comment: The easiest approach to motherboard issues is either warrantee replacement, or buy a new one.

Comment: @ScottSeidman a warranty on a 15 year old board? I wish... OP: Does it have a pc speaker? does it beep?

Comment: @dandavis. Yes its a fairly old system and its not worth replacing the board when for an additional not vey big amount you can buy a more recent new basic system.
There are no beeps or anything. I have also tryied removing-replacing the battery with a new one ,tho its not at all dead (measuring 3V).
The system did start once (not sure why) and worked like a charm untill it was shutdown again. I even managed to run Prime95 for 30 mins without issues. After i shut it down it never came to life again.

Comment: try cooling the board (outside or a fridge) before testing it again. afaict, that's the only variable if it used to work and you didn't change anything to make it not work. If it works for a while, then you could have bad electrolytic capacitors (dang early 2000s) or a physical break in a connection somewhere that cold metal can bridge but warm cannot. If it's thermal (and not caps), the board is effectively "bad", don't bother with it further.

Answer (score 3):

I find the question appropriate and well formulated - then again, I myself am a noob around here.

Parakmi has clearly found the block diagram in a Winbond datasheet, here is a copy:
[image: block diagram of ATX motherboard/PSU power steering]
and he comments on the individual signals quite correctly.

My own knowledge does not go far enough to give you a statistic of typical causes, but from my perspective of a PC repair techie this kind of a problem means that the motherboard gets shipped to the mobo maker's own repair center, where often one of the large chips (here probably the south bridge) gets replaced. Which involves BGA package soldering and requires that you have a spare chip in the first place. Vendors of industrial motherboards do this - e.g. Advantech still can and does repair motherboards for Pentium 4 processors. Noone does that for ancient office-grade PC hardware.

= before you scrap the motherboard, maybe try replacing its 3Volt battery (often a CR2032 coin cell) - the power sequencing blocks inside the south bridge (and the SuperIO chip) depend on that battery-supplied rail, and can make the board misbehave in mysterious ways if the battery is half-way dead.

Comment: "battery-supplied rail"? No, that battery is just for the CMOS/RTC. However, a low (not dead) battery can cause indeterminate values in the CMOS stored settings, which can mis-configure it enough (ex clock multiplier of 0) to prevent a POST. Pull the battery and try to boot it (with the fail-safe defaults) to diagnose that issue.

Comment: No it's not just for CMOS/RTC. The battery provides power to several other functions that have to do with "automatic power-up after a power outage" and whatnot. Just study the datasheets of south bridges and SuperIO chips in some detail - there are tables of what blocks on those chips are dependent on what power "wells", and VBATT is one of them.

Comment: Battery is not the issue as i have tryied with a new one or even without eny battery, The existing is not dead (Measures 3V).
The only thing i can think of (besides an issue with southbridge) is the 32.768Khz oscilator that feeds the southbridge and the superIO. I can't measure it (don't have eqipment) but i will replace it and see what happens. Other than that i can only suspect a local power issue cause maybe by a mosfet...? Some schemtics would be helpfull but can;t find any.

Comment: I confirm, not just for RTC. The same 32768 Hz watch crystal is also used for other stuff like debouncing the power button. If there has been an incident that caused the crystal to stop oscillating, it will not start up unless all board power is turned off first, including standby supplies and battery, and letting the capacitors drain. However such an old motherboard would likely have reached the end of life for electrolytic capacitors already.

Comment: I see that you know the trade :-) Now that you've checked all the easy potential explanations, only the hard stuff remains :-/ This is for the guys who have vendor's documentation, relevant inside know-how about typical causes and are capable of BGA soldering.

Comment: Dried/exploded elyts are one of the easier problems, and likely wouldn't prevent the motherboard from tugging at PS_ON.

Comment: If you say that you don't have an oscilloscope, it might be that the board actually tries to start, but either the board or the PSU give up too early. And the pulse on PS_ON is so short that you cannot see it with basic equipment (a multimeter).

Comment: @frr. The problem is the SUSB signal from the southbridge. From the chip schematic it is clear that it supposed to remain high for the entire operation of the pc. So is the pson signal. When i manually supplied 3.3V to the susb pin the superIO chip turned the PSU on normally. Fans started spinning (including GPUfan) but mobo did not respond with any beeps or other signs of operation. No image on the screen (CPU did get hot tho). I wonder if the BIOS chip is to be examined also.

Comment: IME if the S.B. doesn't give the command to start the ATX PSU, and you do it "out of band", the S.B. also fails to do some other, internal steps to "unlatch" the CPU from reset or something. You could try to investigate if the CPU actually jumps to the start vector, if the BIOS Flash chip starts getting "read" instructions etc... but effectively there's not much you can do to make the system start, if the South Bridge "is not willing", for whatever reason.

Comment: So here is something new. I red that a faulty crystal has the same voltage on both pins. So I tried ot measure the voltage at the ends of the crystal under standby power and for some reason it came back to life... For now it starts normally with beeps and everything... Already ordered a bunch of such crystals, Will replace and let you know. Thanks all for the support

Comment: Now if that turns out to be true, you are my hero :-) The rule "same voltage on both pins" seems odd, god only knows what a digital multimeter will show you for a crystal in operation - but if I'd formulate this as "check the crystal with a scope", that would be valid.